# Kafka reset partition re-consume or not

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If I consume from my topic and manage the offset myself, some records I process are successful then I move the offset on-wards, but occasionally I process records that will throw an exception.  I still need to move the offset onwards.  But at a later point I will need to reset the offset and re-process the failed records.  Is it possible when advancing the offset to set a flag to say that if I consumer over that event again ignore or consume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually - no, this is not possible. Kafka records are read only. I've seen this use case in practice and I will try to give you some suggestions:

- if you experience an error, just copy the message in a separate error topic and move on. This will allow you to replay all error messages at any time from the error topic. That would definitely be my preferred solution - flexible and performant.
- when there is an error - just hang your consumer - preferably enter an infinite loop with an exponential backoff rereading the same message over and over again. We used this strategy together with good monitoring/alerting and log compaction. When something goes wrong we either fix the broken consumer and redeploy our service or if the message itself was broken the producer will fix its bug, republish the message with the same key and log compaction will kick in. The faulty message will be deleted (log compaction). We will be able to move our consumers forward at this point. This requires manual interaction in most cases. If the reason for the fault is a networking issue (e.g. database down) the consumer may recover by itself.
- use local storage (e.g. a database) to store which offsets failed. Then reset the offset and ignore the successfully processed records. This is my least preferred solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle these records is not by resetting the offsets, but by using a [dead-letter queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_letter_queue), essentially, by posting them to another kafka topic for reprocessing later.  That way, your main consumer can focus on processing the records that don't throw exceptions, and some other consumer can constantly be listening and trying to handle the records that are throwing errors.

If that second consumer is still throwing exceptions when trying to reprocess the messages, you can either opt to repost them to the same queue, if the exception is caused by a transient issue (system temporarily unavailable, database issue, network blip, etc), or simply opt to log the message ID and content, as well as the best guess as to what the problem is, for someone to manually look at later.